# How many columns can you have (maximum) in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

What's the max number of columns a mysql table can have?

Comment: This question makes me wince to think of your data model...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840038/max-column-limit-in-mysql-using-myisam

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Why do you care?

Comment: This question is precisely answered in the manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MySQL Reference Manual, there is a *"hard limit"* of 4,096 columns per table.

Check the following [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html) for more information.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Depends on the datatype.

Comment: What if I add 4097th column??...Please dont be approximate?

Comment: @daniel-a-white Are there half-byte data types?