# How many tables can be created in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

How many tables can be created in a mysql database ?

And how many columns can be created in a mysql table ?

How many rows can be inserted into a mysql table ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many columns can you have (maximum) in a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713051/how-many-columns-can-you-have-maximum-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> **How many tables can be created in a mysql database ?**

MySQL has [no limit on the number of databases.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-count-limit.html) The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.

> **And how many columns can be created in a mysql table ?**

There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table. The exact limit depends on [several interacting factors.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

> **How many rows can be inserted into a mysql table ?**

The number of rows is limited by the [maximum size allowed for a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html). This is OS-dependent. You can impose a limit on the number of rows by setting `MAX_ROWS` at table creation time.

#### Reference: [Limits in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits.html)

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on the operating system and version of MySQL. Generally the MySQL file size for tables can be: (5.0 Version)

```
 Operating System       File-size Limit
 Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32     2GB/4GB
 Win32 w/ NTFS          2TB (possibly larger)
 Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit 2GB (LFS: 4GB)
 Linux 2.4+                 4TB(using ext3 file system)
 Solaris 9/10           16TB
 MacOS X w/ HFS+        2TB
 NetWare w/NSS file system  8TB
```

For more information check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Answer (score 4):

Unlimited. 
4096 columns.
Number of row limit is unknown to me.

See for example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html.

Answer (score -1):

Hard cap 4096 columns, but my experience: try not to use VARCHAR, use TINYTEXT.
Otherwise, you will easily reach limit "65,535-byte row size limit" even though you have less than 50 columns in the table.

Answer (score -3):

Maximum row size allowed is 65535 bytes